# Posting variable value rather than name of variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get the entry from a textbox code to go to a php form and have the php form send it to a database. THe problem I'm having is instead of posting the textbox value it posts $code. I'm using mysql and php.

PHP:

```
<?
if( $_POST )
{
$username="***";
$password="***";
    $con = mysql_connect("***",$username,$password);

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("inmoti6_mysite", $con);

    $code = $_POST['code'];


    $code = htmlspecialchars($code); 


    $query = 'INSERT INTO `storycodes`.`storycodes` (`code`) VALUES ("$code");';


    mysql_query($query);

    echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";

    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Doubt this is the issue, but here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Database</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/scripts/database2.php">
  <label>Code:
  <input name="code" type="text" id="code" value="" size="45" />
</label>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but literal usage for variables within quotes are only valid for double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for the variables to be recognized in a string, so change:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `storycodes`.`storycodes` (`code`) VALUES ("$code");';
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `storycodes`.`storycodes` (`code`) VALUES ('$code');";
```

You also have an sql injection problem; I recommend that you switch to PDO (or mysqli) with prepared statements and bound variables. At the very least you should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on your variables before you insert them in the database but as you can see in the manual, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: or $query = 'INSERT INTO storycodes.storycodes (codes) VALUES ("'.$code.'")";

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't post $code, you use $code as a value instead of a variable. problem is related to quotes.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `storycodes`.`storycodes` (`code`) VALUES (\"$code\");";
```

try this one.